Can we stop asking to approve upgrading the metadata in browser extensions?
Given that we now merklise the metadata (for the polkadot ledger app), is it still needed to ask for user permission to upgrade the metadata for polkadot.js and each browser extension? If we can prove that it's the correct metadata then can we automatically update it? That would make the user's experience a lot smoother as often the first thing a user can be confronted with is outdated metadata and would they like to upgrade it for the N extensions they've installed.

I think this even could be an issue in that repo.

You can not prove that it is the correct metadata. How should the UI prove this to the user? It could show you anything. For offline signers you trust them to have the correct firmware, which is way easier than a website that can change any moment. For the extensions, it may looks a little bit different as there is also a little bit more trust involved.
If asking the user to update the metadata makes sense, is actually a different question. I personally don't see such a big advantage in doing this, because the user doesn't know what the correct metadata is and most of the time not if there was an update or similar.
